# Returning vowels

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java, and I am doing my practice on practiceit.

But I got stumbled over this question.

Write a method named `isVowel` that returns whether a `String` is a vowel (a single-letter string containing a, e, i, o, or u, case-insensitively).

```
public static boolean isVowel(String word){

  
   for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++){
  

    char vowels=word.charAt(i);
        if(vowels== 'a'|| vowels =='e' || vowels=='i'|| vowels == 'o' ||  vowels == 'u'|| vowels== 'A'|| vowels =='E' || vowels=='I'|| vowels == 'O' ||  vowels == 'U' ){
           return true;
        } 
       
   }
    return false;
}
```

This code works but when i test it for "hello". It no longer works. I understand it is because the condition is char so it loops one by one and not the word as a whole.But i cant figure out.Will appreciate if someone will give me hints instead of answer.

Comment: According to the question, it should only return true if the length of the string is 1.

Comment: This doesn't make sense as it is. To check whether a "String is a vowel" implies that it is only one character. Right now that seems like it should work if the question was, does a String contain any vowels.

Answer (score 1):

here's the solution you looking for

```
public static boolean isVowel(String x){

    String y=x.toLowerCase();
    if(y.equals("a"))
        return true;
    else if(y.equals("e"))
        return true;
    else if(y.equals("i"))
        return true;
    else if(y.equals("o"))
        return true;
    else if(y.equals("u"))
        return true;
    else 
        return false;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confusing.  A String might have a vowel, but the only proper English "word" with single letter  is "I".

This method should be named "hasVowel" or "containsVowel".  In that case, looping over each letter and returning true if it has a vowel makes sense.

Comment: For instance,when i invoke isVowel("obama"),it should give me fase.But i am getting a true

Comment: No, it'll return "true" when it finds 'o'.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to check whether your string IS a vowel, instead of CONTAINS a vowel, you could write something like:

```
public static boolean isVowel(String word){
    if (word.length()!=1) return false;
    char vowels=word.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
    if(vowels== 'a'|| vowels =='e' || vowels=='i'|| vowels == 'o' ||  vowels == 'u'){
       return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Note that if you did `word = word.toLowerCase()`, there would only need to be half as many comparisons.

Comment: Exactly. I just c/p the code already given. I will edit my answer now.

Comment: I tried out your method and it works.Just clarifying "  if (word.length()!=1) return false;"From my understanding,this means if the word is not equal to 1,the compiler will return false.But when i invoke isVowel("obama"),the lenght is not equal to 1,so it returns false.

Comment: If you need to check whether your word is vowel, anything longer than 1 should return a false.

Comment: Sorry.I kept looking through.But i cant understand.Isn't the question asking me if i see a vowel,i should return true?

Comment: I don't know, what IS really the question here? You stated: 'Write a method named isVowel that returns whether a String is a vowel (a single-letter string containing a, e, i, o, or u, case-insensitively).' The code above does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Given your definition of the function, a `single letter` that is a vowel, this should work.

```
public class StackOverflowAnswer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isVowel("a")); //Returns true
        System.out.println(isVowel("b")); //Returns false
        System.out.println(isVowel("Obama")); //Returns false
        System.out.println(isVowel("ae")); //Returns false, not single letter

    }

    public static boolean isVowel(String word){

           String[] vowels = {"a","e","i","0","u"};

           return Arrays.asList(vowels).contains(word.toLowerCase());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below method worked for me.

```
public static boolean isVowel(String str) {
    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
        return true;
    } else if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
        return true;
    } else if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("i")) {
        return true;
    } else if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("o")) {
        return true;
    } else if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("u")){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```